# Can't get why background image doesn't look the same?

Tags: css, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation plugin.
I have two images: first background of label, when data is valid, and second - invalid.

But they don't look the same with same css attributes.

Here screenshots of my trouble [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNhM8.png)

Here is my code in css file:

```
 label.error {
color:transparent;
display: inline;  
background: url('../images/not_valid.png') no-repeat;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: 5px;
width: 47px;
height: 36px;
}

label.valid {
background: url('../images/valid.png') no-repeat;
display: inline;  
padding: 10px;
margin-left: 5px;
color:transparent;
width: 47px;
height: 36px;
}
```

**EDITED: FILES ON DROPBOX** - [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1ea9k2z6vmsvg58/Pz5X0qRNDv)

Comment: Sry, I can't see your problem...

Comment: @DenMed are you referring to the css attached with the input field???

Comment: can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you can't see screenshot ? i will try jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the image seems to be cropped. So the problem seems to be related to either `background-position` or dimensions or size of the label.

Answer (score 0):

you should inspect those elements with your favorite dom inspector and make sure that there are no other `.valid` and/or `.error` classes defined elsewhere in your css, that affect the styling of your elements. I'm not getting exactly what you mean with

> they don't look the same with same css attributes

so I can only think that there's some more css elsewhere that affects the display of one of your elements.